# Retrieve string from Parse.com

Tags: ios, string, parse-platform

I want to retrieve the current users string value on a specific column from the user class in Parse.com

I have tried this code:

```
NSString *columnString = [[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"columnKey"] stringValue];
```

This code logged an error saying "unrecognized selector sent to instance.."

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: what is your column datatype?

Comment: The datatype of the column is string, so that is not the problem I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your column datatype is String then try below snippet.

```
NSString *str_ColumnString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[PFUser currentUser]valueForKey:@"columnKey"]];
```

Comment: In two minutes I can :)